# Is there a general formula that covers all numeric palindromes that are divisible by 3?

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, palindrome

I am curious about the answer to the question:

Is there a general formula that covers all numeric palindrome that are divisible by 3? If so what is it?

I had this one form $j(10^n+1), j=3,6\ and\ 9$. But it does not yield all.

I also had this one $j(\sum_{k=0}^n10^k)$. But again it does not yield all.

And as the digits of palindrome increases I think more and more forms will be needed.

Can someone help me answerning my question, thanks a lot everyone.

Comment: I think you should focus on particular cases of the number of digits: For example, if this number is 3, note that a number is palindrome and divisible by 3 iff it's of the form $a_0+a_110+a_010^2=a_0(1+10^2)+a_110$. In order for it to be divisible by 3, it must satisfy $a_1-a_0= 0$ (mod 3), the number of couples $(a_0,a_1)$ that satisfy this is very easy to calculate (I didn't take the time). Can you generalize this?

Comment: Thanks @Devilathor will try to generalize it. But then I think as the number of digits increases it becomes complicated.

Comment: There's a table of the first 50 such numbers at https://oeis.org/A045638